# Algorithm to find the mode in a unimodal array

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, arrays

I am given the following problem in an Algorithms class:

> Assume that you are given an array A[1 . . . n] of distinct numbers.
>   You are told that the sequence of numbers in the array is unimodal, in
>   other words, there is an index i such that the sequence A[1 . . . i]
>   is increasing (A[j] < A[j + 1] for 1 ≤ j < i), and the sequence A[i .
>   . . n] is decreasing. The index i is called the mode of A. Give an
>   O(log n) algorithm that find the mode of A

I have written this draft solution as my solution but I want to make sure that this is an acceptable CORRECT solution.

My Algorithm:

```
FIND_MODE(A)
n = A.length
if n == 1
    return 1

mid = floor(n/2)
if A[mid] < A[mid+ 1]
    return FIND_MODE(A[1 … mid])
else
    return mid + FIND_MODE(A[mid+1 … n])
```

Is it this acceptable and correct pseudocode algorithm?

Is it correct that this is a Big-O(log n) algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost correct. Just a small correction. It should be

```
if A[mid] > a[mid+1]
```

If two consecutive elements are increasing then they are in the increasing portion of the array, so the mode is to the right. Hence the correction.

Answer (score 1):

There's a neat, provably "optimal" (in some sense) algorithm for this problem in [Structure and interpretation of computer programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) (free online version) by Abelson and Sussman. It involves partitioning the line in two pieces in a ratio [$\phi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). I am not sure where the original algorithm came from in the literature, but maybe someone else can cite it.

Comment: ps am looking for an exact analysis of the runtime of this algorithm also.

Answer (score 0):

Prologue:

```
Let L be a list of integers.
Let L[p : q] be an nonempty slice, i.e., 0 ≤ p < q ≤ len(L).
We say that L[p : q] is unimodal iff there is a natural number m such that

(a) p≤m<q;
(b) L[p : m + 1] strictly increasing;
(c) L[m : q] is strictly decreasing.

Furthermore, such a number m, if it exists, is call the mode of L[p : q].

Since L is the same as L[0 : len(L)], we also say that L is unimodal if L[0 : len(L)] is unimodal.
```

Algorithm:

```
def Mode(A,p,q): 

if p+1==q:
   return A[p] 
else:
   m=⌊p+q⌋ 2

ifA[m−1]<A[m]: 
   return Mode(A,m,q)
else:
   return Mode(A,p,m)
```

Proof of Correctness:

Let P(n) denote the assertion that if A is a list of integers, 0 ≤ p < q ≤ len(A), A[p : q] is unimodal, and n = q − p, then M ax(A, p, q) terminates and returns the maximum element of A[p : q].

Note that we are using q − p (length of the slice being considered) as size of input.

We prove that for all integers n ∈ N, n ≥ 1, P (n) holds.

**Base Case**: Let n = 1. Then q − p = 1, or equivalently, p + 1 = q.
Thus A[p : q] is a slice of one element, and A[p] is its maximum element.

By Line 2, A[p] is returned as wanted.

**Induction Step**: Let n ∈ N,n > 1. 
Suppose for all j ∈ N, 1 ≤ j < n,P(j) holds. [IH]

**WTP**: P(n) holds.

Since q − p = n > 1, Lines 4-8 run.
There are two cases to consider.

*Case 1: A[m − 1] < A[m].*

Then by Line 6, Max(A,m,q) is called and returned.

By Line 4 and Hint 2, p < m < q, and so 1 ≤ q − m < q − p.

By the IH, M ax(A, m, q) terminates and returns the maximum element of A[m : q].

Since A[m − 1] < A[m], the mode of A[p : q] must equal the mode of A[m : q].

So the maximum element of A[p : q] equals the maximum element of A[m : q].
Therefore M ax(A, p, q) terminates and returns the maximum element of A[p : q], as wanted.

*Case 2: A[m − 1] > A[m]:*

Similar to Case 1; left as an exercise.